# Java Timestamp Gap

Tags: java, time, activemq-classic

I meet one problem when using below code.

`Timestamp starttime = new java.sql.Timestamp( Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());`

I have two projects, A and B (now they are deployed on my local machine), and one queue. A keeps pushing objects into queue, B keeps popping objects from queue. I'm recording the push and pop event, and try to store the event time into database.

Below are two records in the database. The first column is event_id, second column uses above code to generate event happened time. We can see that, although **"pushed to queue" event** have **a smaller event_id**, which means that it is inserted into database **before "pop from queue"**, **"pushed to queue" event's** time is **slightly later than "pop from queue"**. However, "pushed to queue" should have a **smaller event_id** and **an earlier time**. Can you help me figure out what is happening here?

**223636** **"2017-07-07 22:27:20.129"** "localhost.localdomain";"Message popped from queue"

**223635** **"2017-07-07 22:27:20.13"** "localhost.localdomain";"Message pushed to queue"

Comment: Assuming the output is based on [Timestamp#toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html#toString--), the push event does have an earlier time than the pop event.  That is, 13 ns < 129 ns.  If A and B are running in different JVMs it might still be possible though: 1) A publish to queue 2) B pop queue and write to database  3) A write to database.  Depends on the code and process/thread switching.

Comment: @AndrewS Actually, both A and B call another project C to store the event